# Getting text field input scope from regex

Tags: c#, .net, regex

When a textbox receives focus I want to show an on-screen keyboard.  There are several keyboards that I can show based on the input scope of the field.  The problem is that the textbox's expected user input is server-driven and I am not provided with an input scope property (nor can I add one). In fact, all I have is the regex to validate the user's input for the field.

Based on any regex string, what is the best way to determine an input scope for a textbox?

Input scopes are: Name (letters keyboard only), PhoneNumber (numbers only keyboard), etc.

Typical regex: "^[0-9]{4,4}$", "^[0-9]{10,10}$" but may be much more complex.

Comment: You're going to have to clarify what you're doing. If the regex can only be applied after after the user has entered their text, what's the point of the InputScope?

Comment: reversing a regEx to see if it expects a String or Number would be overkill. Simply have a list of the fields and if the value should be String or Number then use that list to determine which keyboard to show.

Comment: I am using the regex to validate user-input on submit, I'd like to also use it to show the correct keyboard on focus.

Comment: How do you know which regex goes to which textbox?

Comment: I know what the regex is per textbox well before showing the form, I don't need to wait to submit, I guess I should have specified that this is for a client app in WPF.

Comment: So if you know what regex belongs to which textbox in advance, wouldn't you know what input scope that textbox will need?

Comment: Yes! But there is no explicit property on the server that says "this field is a phone number" only a regex pattern for validation. I'm asking what would be the best way to derive the input scope from the regex pattern.

Answer (score 3):

Hard coding a map of regex's to input types seems like an option, but a poor one.

Do you know how many classes of inputs there are? I'll assume you do. You need to create a sample set of inputs which match various input classes, and then make a truth table to compare it to, like

```
EXAMPLE      | PHONE | NAME | TEXT |   
2061234567   | T     | F    | T    |
206.123.4567 | T     | F    | T    |
hello        | F     | T    | T    |
brian        | F     | T    | T    |
bADSFj@$$    | F     | F    | T    |
```

Take the regex for the field, run the example strings through the regex, and compare the match vs. not match to a table that maps truth values to input classes. Here's an example solution, though you may want to use some heuristic instead of doing exact matches.  (Java):

```
int PHONE_CLASS = 0x18; // 11000 - the truth table value from above
...
Map<int, Keyboard> keyboardMap;
keyboardMap.put(PHONE_CLASS, phoneKeyboard);
...
Keyboard inferKeyboard(Pattern regex) {
  int matches = 0;
  for (String example : examples) {
    matches = matches << 1;
    if (regex.matches(example)) { matches++; }
  }
  if (!keyboardMap.containsKey(matches)) { return GENERIC_KEYBOARD; }
  return keyboardMap.get(matches);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The trick is to specify the formats for each input scope within an if conditional in a regex pattern. I start out with a phone number because it appears to be the most limiting; numbers, dash, period slash). Then I work my way to others. *Note the regex phone pattern is not super robust so you may need to tweak it.*. Once found check the regex pattern to see what text is put into the named match capture group. If the named match capture group has text, viola! one has identified what it is.

This example has three types, Phone, Address (address is numbers then a space then text) followed by the default of text. But you can add more ifs internally. The pattern is commented for easier use.

```
void Main()
{

    Console.WriteLine ("303-867-5309".DetermineScope() == InputScope.Phone); // True
    Console.WriteLine ("1811 South Quebec Way".DetermineScope() == InputScope.Address); // True
    Console.WriteLine ("Turk 181".DetermineScope() == InputScope.Text); // True

}

public enum InputScope
    {
       Phone,           // Digits and dividers
       Address,         // number space then text
         Text,            // Everything is text...final catch all.
    };


public static class TestCaseExtensions
{

    public static InputScope DetermineScope(this string text)
    {

        string pattern = @"
(?(^[\d.\-/\\]+$)           # If: First check for phone; just numbers and dividers (no spaces)
   (?<Phone>[\d.\-/\\]+)    #    Place into Phone named capture group
 |                          # Else: start a new check
   (?(^\d+\s\w+)            # If Check for address (if Address)
     (?<Address>.*)       #    Looks like its an address, place into address capture group
    |                     # Else
     (?<Text>.*)          #   Nope just text, place into text capture group
   )
)";

    var result = InputScope.Text; // Default to the lowest...text

    // Ignore allows us to document pattern; it is not related to processing text.
    var match = Regex.Match(text, pattern, RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace);

    if (match.Success)
    {
        result = 
        Enum.GetValues(typeof(InputScope))
            .OfType<InputScope>()
            .Where (tp => match.Groups[tp.ToString()].Success)
            .First ();

    }

    return result;

    }

}
```

I've written more on the subject: [Regular Expressions and the If Conditional](http://omegacoder.com/?p=56).